# Alterar um método do Repositório Genérico para retornar com AsNoTracking - EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tenho um repositório genérico, em especial, o método `GetbyId`, no qual desejo alterá-lo para retornar um resultado com `AsNoTracking` ou Não, conforme a necessidade. Como faço isso?

Minha Interface:

```
TEntity GetById(int id, bool @readonly = false);
```

Meu Repositório Genérico:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly RetaguardaContext Db;
        protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

        public Repository(RetaguardaContext context)
        {
            Db = context;
            DbSet = Db.Set<TEntity>();
        }       
        public virtual TEntity GetById(int id, bool @readonly = false)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }
}
```

Comment: uma dica, leia o [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/88361). Sempre suas perguntas vem sem formatação, e, você não é novo aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método find não tem sentido ser utilizado com o AsNoTracking, visto que, pela descrição do mesmo, é informado que primeiro é checado se o objeto está sendo rastreado:

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with
>   the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it
>   is returned immediately without making a request to the database.
>   Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the
>   given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the
>   context and returned. If no entity is found, then null is returned.

Uma possível alternativa para o seu caso, é utilizar uma classe Entidade como base:

```
public class Entidade 
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
}
```

E suas entidades herdam dessa classe.

No seu repositório, você altera a constraint do generic TEntity para ser uma Entidade

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entidade 
{
    // construtores e propriedades... 

    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id, bool @readonly = false)
    {
        if (@readonly) 
            return DbSet.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    // seus outros métodos...
}
```

Assim, todos os seus métodos genéricos terão acesso à propriedade ID.

Utilizar o find como na outra resposta, faz com que o EF verifique no tracking se a entidade está lá, carregue do banco, coloque em cache, só para remover (altera o estado para detached). Na maneira como expliquei, fará com que o EF nem tente adicionar a entidade no tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Baseado nessa [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967116/how-to-combine-find-and-asnotracking).

O Método `Find()` não possui o `AsNoTracking()`, porém você pode alterar o estado dele para `Detached`, que é o equivalente.

Seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id, bool @readonly = false)
{
    var entity =  DbSet.Find(id);

    if(@readonly)
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;

    return entity;
}
```